# Dart/Flutter Organizational problem with abstract class

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make a photo editing app in Flutter with a dynamic toolbar. By this I mean the tool options in the toolbar change when the user selects a different "element" such as a text box or photo. The user should be able to edit the currently selected element using the tools in the toolbar.
Unfortunately I can think of no possible way to do this.
Each element needs its own set of tools, and these tools MUST be a member of the _state class because when the user uses the tools, it will change the state of the element. For example, the change font tool will change the font of the text element.

So I honestly don't think what I am trying to accomplish is possible but am open to suggestions.

I tried creating an abstract class so that I can store all my elements in one array. This does not work because the state class is the one that implements the shared getTools method. For example, I have a TextLayer class and a _TextLayerState class to manage its state. _TextLayerState implements the abstract element class because the getTools function MUST go in the state class so that I can implement the onTap() funcionality to change its state. I can not put TextLayer in a  list because TextLayer is not an element, only its state implements that class!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this is possible.

Just store the toolbar elements in a list, in the state widget,
then add and remove elements you want and call `setState((){});`.

For example:

```dart
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  List<Widget> _toolbarItems=[];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
      children:[
        YourCustomToolbar(
          children: _toolbarItems,
          ...
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain this very well. Every element will have its own set of toolbar iconButtons. For example, a text element might have a button for changing font size and font color. These tools MUST reside inside the _textState class because clicking on the tool icons will change the state of the element (increasing font size for example). I need a way to display these icons on my home page. I won't know what they are on runtime, The user has to click on an element before I know which set to display.